# session create using spring security registration

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-security, spring-data

I am working with the registration processing using the spring security following the article of building https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration. As per this article, the `HTML` pages take the input and insert it into the database.

I am working with a Flutter application on the front-end. I want that when the user requests to **reset password** a link is sent to the email of a user and when the user clicks on the verification link it will create a session and redirect to the UI Page on the app to write the **New Password**. When the user enters the **New Password** it will update the password of that user.

**updatePassword.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"/>
    <style>
.password-verdict{
color:#000;
}

    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/pwstrength.js}"></script>
    <title th:text="#{message.updatePassword}">update password</title>
</head>
<body>
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE')">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 th:text="#{message.resetYourPassword}">reset</h1>
            <form>
                <br/>

                <label class="col-sm-2" th:text="#{label.user.password}">password</label>
                <span class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-control" id="password" name="newPassword" type="password"
                                              value=""/></span>
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
                <br/><br/>
                <label class="col-sm-2" th:text="#{label.user.confirmPass}">confirm</label>
                <span class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-control" id="matchPassword" type="password" value=""/></span>
                <div id="globalError" class="col-sm-12 alert alert-danger" style="display:none"
                     th:text="#{PasswordMatches.user}">error
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <br/><br/>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="savePass()"
                            th:text="#{message.updatePassword}">submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
var serverContext = [[@{/}]];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        savePass(event);
    });

    $(":password").keyup(function(){
        if($("#password").val() != $("#matchPassword").val()){
            $("#globalError").show().html(/*[[#{PasswordMatches.user}]]*/);
        }else{
            $("#globalError").html("").hide();
        }
    });

    options = {
            common: {minChar:6},
            ui: {
                showVerdictsInsideProgressBar:true,
                showErrors:true,
                errorMessages:{
                      wordLength: /*[[#{error.wordLength}]]*/,

                    }
                }
        };
     $('#password').pwstrength(options);
});

function savePass(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".alert").html("").hide();
    $(".error-list").html("");
    if($("#password").val() != $("#matchPassword").val()){
        $("#globalError").show().html(/*[[#{PasswordMatches.user}]]*/);
        return;
    }
    var formData= $('form').serialize();
    $.post(serverContext + "user/savePassword",formData ,function(data){
        window.location.href = serverContext + "login?message="+data.message;
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        if(data.responseJSON.error.indexOf("InternalError") > -1){
            window.location.href = serverContext + "login?message=" + data.responseJSON.message;
        }
        else{
            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseJSON.message);
            $.each( errors, function( index,item ){
                $("#globalError").show().html(item.defaultMessage);
            });
            errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseJSON.error);
            $.each( errors, function( index,item ){
                $("#globalError").show().append(item.defaultMessage+"<br/>");
            });
        }
    });
}


    </script>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This will create the session and update the password perfectly.
But I want to send a post request and a **newPassword** to store in the database. But unable to create the session.

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/savePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String savePassword(@RequestParam("newPassword") String newPassword) {
        final User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        userService.changeUserPassword(user, newPassword);
        return "Password has been changed successfully. ";
    }
```

This

```
final User user = (User) 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

is not creating the session of the user when I directly hit the URL from UI App.

> Please tell me the way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to understand what happened wrong. If I understood correctly, and you follow this example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-i-forgot-my-password is impeccable, then at the time of checking the token from the letter, you should have been authorized.

I guess, it  should be here

```
public String validatePasswordResetToken(long id, String token) {
    PasswordResetToken passToken = 
      passwordTokenRepository.findByToken(token);
    if ((passToken == null) || (passToken.getUser()
        .getId() != id)) {
        return "invalidToken";
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if ((passToken.getExpiryDate()
        .getTime() - cal.getTime()
        .getTime()) <= 0) {
        return "expired";
    }

    User user = passToken.getUser();
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
      user, null, Arrays.asList(
      new SimpleGrantedAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth); // authorization after validation of reset token
    return null;
}
```

Please, give some more about your situation. Give me a full example of this. Or you just what to save a password directly?

Comment: Sir, I am working with the "Flutter" app as frontend. I just want to redirect to an app page where the user could enter the `new-password` but I am unable to do how to direct signal to flutter app after verification of token.